Oracle SQL Query To Calculate Length of Service For Employees With Multiple Termination and ReHire Dates
I am trying to calculate the length of service of our employees within our Oracle database. Below is a table with some example data for two employees. The calculation would be from the first HIREDATE to the subsequent TERMDATE and then the next REHIREDATE to the next TERMDATE and so on. These will be active employees so the last TERMDATE would be calculated against SYSDATE.
The outcome I'm looking for is the total length of service for each employee in years and months. EMPNO 10166 = 18 years 2 months and EMPNO 06680 = 18 years 6 months.



EMPNO
HIREDATE
TERMDATE
REHIREDATE




10166
05-FEB-05
15-SEP-07
17-JAN-08


10166
05-FEB-05
24-MAR-14
16-AUG-14


10166
05-FEB-05
23-AUG-16
06-FEB-17


06680
21-SEP-98
20-MAR-08
13-JUL-09


06680
21-SEP-98
17-OCT-11
29-AUG-16


06680
21-SEP-98
27-JUL-17
24-SEP-18




with data(empno, hiredate, termdate, rehiredate) as (
    select '10166', to_date('05-FEB-05', 'DD-MON-RR'), to_date('15-SEP-07', 'DD-MON-RR'), to_date('17-JAN-08', 'DD-MON-RR') union all
    select '10166', to_date('05-FEB-05', 'DD-MON-RR'), to_date('24-MAR-14', 'DD-MON-RR'), to_date('16-AUG-14', 'DD-MON-RR') union all
    select '10166', to_date('05-FEB-05', 'DD-MON-RR'), to_date('23-AUG-16', 'DD-MON-RR'), to_date('06-FEB-17', 'DD-MON-RR') union all
    select '06680', to_date('21-SEP-98', 'DD-MON-RR'), to_date('20-MAR-08', 'DD-MON-RR'), to_date('13-JUL-09', 'DD-MON-RR') union all
    select '06680', to_date('21-SEP-98', 'DD-MON-RR'), to_date('17-OCT-11', 'DD-MON-RR'), to_date('29-AUG-16', 'DD-MON-RR') union all
    select '06680', to_date('21-SEP-98', 'DD-MON-RR'), to_date('27-JUL-17', 'DD-MON-RR'), to_date('24-SEP-18', 'DD-MON-RR') -- union all
)
select d.empno, trunc(delta / 365) as years,
    trunc((delta - trunc(delta / 365) * 365) / (365/12)) as months
from (
    select d.empno, sum(delta) as delta from (
        select d.*, nvl(termdate - lag(rehiredate,1) over(partition by empno order by hiredate,termdate),
            termdate - hiredate) 
            + case when lead(hiredate) over(partition by empno order by hiredate,termdate) is null
                then sysdate - rehiredate else 0 end
            as delta 
        from data d
    ) d
    group by d.empno
) d
order by empno
;




empno
years
months




06680
18
5


10166
18
2




I would be querying a view in our database and we can call it EMP_LOS. How would I use your solution if I'm querying EMP_LOS?

are you serious? ... you remove the WITH and replace "from data" by "from EMP_LOS"

You can use the LEAD analytic function and then aggregate:
SELECT empno,
       FLOOR( 
         MONTHS_BETWEEN(
           MIN(termdate),
           MIN(hiredate)
         ) + SUM(period)
       ) * INTERVAL '1' MONTH AS time_employed
FROM   (  
  SELECT empno,
         hiredate,
         termdate,
         MONTHS_BETWEEN(
           LEAD(termdate, 1, SYSDATE) OVER (PARTITION BY empno ORDER BY termdate),
           rehiredate
         ) AS period
  FROM   emp_los
)
GROUP BY empno

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE emp_los (empno, hiredate, termdate, rehiredate) AS
  SELECT '10166', DATE '2005-02-05', DATE '2007-09-15', DATE '2008-01-17' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '10166', DATE '2005-02-05', DATE '2014-03-24', DATE '2014-08-16' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '10166', DATE '2005-02-05', DATE '2016-08-23', DATE '2017-02-06' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '06680', DATE '1998-09-21', DATE '2008-03-20', DATE '2009-07-13' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '06680', DATE '1998-09-21', DATE '2011-10-17', DATE '2016-08-29' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '06680', DATE '1998-09-21', DATE '2017-07-27', DATE '2018-09-24' FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



EMPNO
TIME_EMPLOYED




06680
+000000018-05


10166
+000000018-02



fiddle
